# My apps is crashing when player is play

Tags: ios

I have a very simple app that is supposed to only play an audio file on view. Instead my  Xcode is crashing.

I am using Xcode version 6. I have implemented the AVFoundation Framework

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
      {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Crowd_cheering"                            
        ofType:@"m4a" ];  
        NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
        NSError *error;
        self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
        [self.player play];
}
```

Comment: Well...what does `error` contain?!

Comment: where r u testing on device or simulator?

Comment: @borrrden NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter showing Exception

Comment: check what value  of audioPath may be nil

Comment: That means that the file is not in your bundle at that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Try like this with error condition:

```
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
        pathForResource:@"Moderato"
        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    NSError *error;
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                     initWithContentsOfURL:url
                     error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
            NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
            _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
            [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
```

//Before that add import AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h and add delegate AVAudioPlayerDelegate

//then Implement the AVAudioPlayerDelegate Protocol Methods like this

```
    -(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
     {

     }
    -(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
     {

     }
    -(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
     {

     }
    -(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
    {

    }
```

Make sure u connected ur play button properly or not and also check whether you Added an Audio File to the Project Resources properly.